# Listplot legends showing very small point size

Tags: plotting, legending

I have the following code:

```
Mobility210419ZcI = {{10, 14.15}, {10, 16.36}, {10, 17.99}, {40, 
    14.86}, {40, 19.65}, {40, 17.22}, {100, 20.28}, {100, 
    19.16}, {100, 19.18}, {150, 21.86}, {150, 20.7}, {150, 
    22.75}, {200, 22.06}, {200, 22.05}, {200, 20.46}, {250, 
    20.12}, {250, 25.44}, {250, 24.7}, {300, 24.21}, {300, 
    22.76}, {300, 23.52}};
Mobility210419ZcIData = 
 KeyValueMap[List]@
  GroupBy[Mobility210419ZcI   , First -> Last, 
   Around[Mean@#, StandardDeviation@#] &]
Al0point58GaNexp = 
 ListPlot[Mobility210419ZcIData, PlotRange -> {{0, 305}, {0, 800}}, 
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Temperature (K)", 
    "Mobility (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(2\)]\)/V.s)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize -> 0.025, Thick, Brown}  , 
  GridLines -> None, ImageSize -> 400, FrameStyle -> Black, 
  IntervalMarkersStyle -> LightGray, PlotLegends -> {"E"}]
```

It gives this output
[image]

You can clearly see that the legend point has a very small size. How should I correct it?

Comment: I take it you are referring to the almost invisible dot, next to the letter E on the right of the plot?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Comment: Use `PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"E"}, LegendMarkers -> Graphics[Disk[]]]`. If you want to enlarge it further, play with `LegendMarkerSize` option in the `PointLegend`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Bed_Izd really had this, but I thought to post a complete answer before the end of the day.

Happy to withdrawal it if @Bed_Izd wants to post.

```
Mobility210419ZcI = {{10, 14.15}, {10, 16.36}, {10, 17.99}, {40, 
    14.86}, {40, 19.65}, {40, 17.22}, {100, 20.28}, {100, 
    19.16}, {100, 19.18}, {150, 21.86}, {150, 20.7}, {150, 
    22.75}, {200, 22.06}, {200, 22.05}, {200, 20.46}, {250, 
    20.12}, {250, 25.44}, {250, 24.7}, {300, 24.21}, {300, 
    22.76}, {300, 23.52}};

Mobility210419ZcIData = 
  KeyValueMap[List]@
   GroupBy[Mobility210419ZcI, First -> Last, 
    Around[Mean@#, StandardDeviation@#] &];

Al0point58GaNexp = ListPlot[
  Mobility210419ZcIData, PlotRange -> {{0, 305}, {0, 800}}, 
  Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Temperature (K)", 
    "Mobility (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(cm\), \(2\)]\)/V.s)"},
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15},
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize -> 0.025, Thick, Brown},
  GridLines -> None,
  ImageSize -> 400,
  FrameStyle -> Black,
  IntervalMarkersStyle -> LightGray,
  PlotLegends ->
   PointLegend[{"E"},
    LegendMarkers -> Graphics[Disk[]],
    LegendMarkerSize -> Medium
    ]]
```

`LegendMarkerSize` give you all the control you'd need.

[image]